# Drop and recreate primary key on an SQL Server temporary table

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, temp-tables, alter-table

I need to drop and rebuild a primary key in a temp table in SQL Server.  The most common solution requires you to enter the name of the PK index.  However, since this is inside a store procedure, doing so limits any parallel use of this sp.

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable (Date_ DATETIME NOT NULL, Name_ CHAR(50) NOT NULL, VALUE_ INT )
ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Date_, Name_)
```

Now I need to drop this primary key and create a new one on just the Name_ column.

For e.g.,

```
ALTER TABLE #mytable DROP OLD PK
ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Name_)
```

Comment: Just drop and recreate the temp table? It seems odd to want to change the PK (clustered index) around the dataset..

Comment: DROP TABLE #mytable CREATE TABLE #mytable .. gives an error when you hit Run (F5).  I use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'm sure I've done this before, but don't have SSMS available atm. What is the error? Also include any relevant error messages associated with the initial question/approach.

Comment: Error: "There is already an object named '#mytable' in the database"

Comment: Make sure the cursor is at the top of the editor/query window (SSMS will quite happily, to my chagrin, start at a particular line/statement which sounds like it might be at the CREATE TABLE)

Comment: Doesn't help.  I put the mouse cursor by the top row (if that is what you meant?)

Comment: Why does it need to be a PK? If you create a unique clustered index (rather than unique constraint) then you can happily have concurrent temporary tables with that same index name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL and `NEWID()` will give you a unique identifier that you can append to the PK's name.

```
DECLARE @GUID VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @GUID = REPLACE(NEWID(), '-', '')

PRINT @GUID


CREATE TABLE #mytable (Date_ DATETIME NOT NULL, Name_ CHAR(50) NOT NULL, VALUE_ INT )
EXEC('ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_'+@GUID+' PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Date_, Name_)')


EXEC('ALTER TABLE #mytable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_'+@GUID)
ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Name_)

DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

Comment: The problem with dynamic query and temp tables is the sp will look for the temp table in tempdb probably.  I'm getting the error: "Cannot find the object "#mytable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Comment: @Maddy It will work perfectly. U can access a already created temp table inside a dynamic query. U cannot access a temp table outside of dynamic query which is created inside a dynamic query.!!

Comment: @maddy, what version is your rdbms? This is working perfectly for me on sql-server-2012 ...

Comment: @maddy, you are creating the stored procedure and altering the index within the same session, correct? Pradeep is correct, since the table is created outside of the dynamic SQL session it should be able to be accessed via Dynamic SQL regardless.

Comment: @Pradeep you are right.  This works well inside my sp now..thanks to you two. I have accepted the answer.

Comment: @AHiggins sorry I know this is an old thread, but question for you. Do you know if you have to drop the PK for a temporary table or is dropping the temp table enough? I tried both ways and I can't make a determination.

Comment: Hey @dyslexicanaboko - I've always considered dropping the table to be sufficient, but can't link to anything specific to prove it.